# How can I Incrementally number a transaction log backup filename?

Tags: sql-server

I need to create transaction log backups of a database with the filenames somehow numbered incrementally, one per hour, throughout the day.

Example:

9am - mydb**01**.trn

10am - mydb**02**.trn

11am - mydb**03**.trn

etc.

I do not want the date or time appended to these because our SAN snapshots will take care of the versioning. These names have to be the same every day.

I would like to do this without having to create a job for each hour of the day. I just haven't been able to figure this out using basic T-SQL which is the limit of my T-SQL skills. I know I could just create a bunch of jobs with standard backup commands in them like below, with a different filename and scheduled time, however there has to be a better way.

```
BACKUP LOG [mydb] TO DISK = N'X:\SQLBackups\mydb01.trn.trn'
    ,NAME = N'mydb_backup'
    ,COMPRESSION
    ,STATS = 10
    ,CHECKSUM
GO
```

Comment: Have you reviewed the T-Sql documentation for date and time functions? `datepart` might be useful here?

Comment: So what happens when you take more than one log backup in an hour?

Comment: I would guess if the job is scheduled more frequently the OP could also include the minutes in a similar fashion. Personally I would suggest using a full ISO date&time to remove any ambiguity in names though.

Comment: The worry is that an ad-hoc backup overwrites an earlier one and breaks the log chain.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all for the questions and suggestions. I will address these one at a time.
Stu, I have looked over the docs and without heavy programming I didn't see anything that could help.

Comment: David, The log chain doesn't matter now because I just found out that we will not be keep the transaction logs past one day which negates this entire post.
I apologize for wasting everyone's time on this. If I had known about this earlier I would have never asked the question. Thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Backup Log` permits you to use variables, you could use a variable for your disk name and assign it the appropriate name, for example:

```
declare @diskname nvarchar(100)=N'X:\SQLBackups\' + N'MyDb' 
                  + Right(Concat(N'0', DatePart(hour, GetDate())),2) + N'.trn'

print @diskname

backup log [mydb] to  disk = @diskname, ...etc
```

Comment: Stu, thank you for the code. It doesn't really help me now but maybe it will in the future, or it may help someone else so I will go ahead and mark this answered.